# Use of Nested NSArray in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have two `NSArray`. One is holding some `.png` and another is holding some durations `0.04`. 
Like:

```
imageArray 
(
    "smiley64_1_1.png",
    "smiley64_1_2.png",
    ...................
    ...................
    "smiley64_1_19.png",
    "smiley64_1_20.png"
)
```

And:

```
durationArray 
(
    "0.04",
    "0.04",
    ......
    ......
    "0.05",
    "0.02"
)
```

I show them in an `UIImageView` with `performSelector` so that they can act like animation (Emoticons).

```
-(void) imageAnimationWithImage:(NSArray *) imgarray andDurationArray:(NSArray *) durationArr
{
    if (count == imgarray.count)
    {
        count = 0;
        [self imageAnimationWithImage:imgarray andDurationArray:durationArr];
    }
    else
    {
        emoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgarray objectAtIndex:count]];

        double delay = [[durationArr objectAtIndex:count] doubleValue];
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self imageAnimationWithImage:imgarray andDurationArray:durationArr];
        });

        count++;
    }
}
```

Call it from this method:

```
-(void) createScrollWithImageArray:(NSArray *) imgArray AndDurationArray:(NSArray *) durArray AndName:(NSString *) name withCount:(NSInteger) i
{
    int imageViewPointx = 8;
    int imageViewPointy = 8;
    int imageViewWidth = 42;
    int imageViewHeight = 43;
    int gapBetweenImageViews = 12;
    i = i - 1;

    emoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [emoImageView setFrame:CGRectMake((imageViewPointx +((imageViewWidth + gapBetweenImageViews) *i)), imageViewPointy, imageViewWidth, imageViewHeight)];


    count = 0;
    [self imageAnimation];

    [emoImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];

    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [emoImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [scrollView addSubview:emoImageView];
}
```

This last method is calling from a `for loop`. When I run it, In every time, I get 3 information.

1. Array name (Frame1)
2. ImageArray (.png)
3. DurationArray (time interval)

In this case it call, only one time because I have only one frame information (image name & duration). And it working perfectly. But if I have more than one set of information like:

```
imageArray 
(
    "smiley64_2_1.png",
    "smiley64_2_2.png",
    ...................
    ...................
    "smiley64_2_19.png",
    "smiley64_2_20.png"
)

durationArray 
(
    "0.02",
    "0.02",
    ......
    ......
    "0.05",
    "0.02"
)
```

And:

```
imageArray 
(
    "smiley64_2_1.png",
    "smiley64_2_2.png",
    ...................
    ...................
    "smiley64_2_19.png",
    "smiley64_2_20.png"
)

durationArray 
(
    "0.02",
    "0.02",
    ......
    ......
    "0.05",
    "0.02"
)
```

It is not working. In fact it have only animated the last arrays information. So, my question is how could I animated all set of information at the same time in different UIImageView? If you have any query, please ask me.
A lot of thanks for advance. Have a good day.

**Addition**: Project code:
["Click here"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4rpzj07ku8j4a3/ImageSequenceAnimationWithMultipleDuration.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. You say you "get 3 information", then list Array name (Frame1), imageArray, and DurationArray.

I don't understand what the first one is. "Array name (Frame1)". What is that?

Your method createScrollWithImageArray takes 4 parameters, including AndName and withCount. It isn't at all clear what those are for.

You increment your count variable, i, but then never do anything else with it, so the fact that it is incremented is meaningless.

I **think** what you are asking to do is pass in different arrays of images names and durations, and have your code animate using those different arrays.

It looks to me like you're pretty close. Just add 2 parameters to 
In createScrollWithImageArray, just pass the image name array and duration array to the imageAnimation method, and use those arrays instead of global arrays for doing the animation. Then in createScrollWithImageArray, pass the image name array and duration array to imageAnimation.

As for what you want with the array name and count, I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir. Yes, I have escaped a lot of things. Because it cover up my real need. I just updated my post with sample code. If you want you can download and run it. Yes, All I want to animate all the images (image names & duration) [may be 3 or 5 set] at a same time.

Comment: (i just update my post & update my sample code as well)
I pass the two arrays to `imageAnimation`. But it is not working for multiple 
 (image names array & duration array) arrays. I think, I have to use different `UIImageView`. Because, when the second set is coming, it stops the previous animation and start new one.

Comment: Yes, if you want 2 animations to run at the same time, they have to operate on different image views.